# Android, AsyncTask not calling onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

Kindly suggest me a fix for the problem:

I am unable to figure out why onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute from AsyncTask class are not getting called after execution of doInBackground or onPreExecute.

This is my Fragment class rendering Youtube Playlists where I would like to implement ProgressBar.

```
public class YouTubeRecyclerViewFragment extends Fragment {
// the fragment initialization parameter
private static final String ARG_YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_IDS = "YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_IDS";
private String[] mPlaylistIds;
private ArrayList<String> mPlaylistTitles;
//private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerViewPager mRecyclerView;
private PlaylistVideos mPlaylistVideos;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private PlaylistCardAdapter mPlaylistCardAdapter;
private YouTube mYouTubeDataApi;


public static YouTubeRecyclerViewFragment newInstance(YouTube youTubeDataApi, String[] playlistIds) {
    YouTubeRecyclerViewFragment fragment = new YouTubeRecyclerViewFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putStringArray(ARG_YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_IDS, playlistIds);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    fragment.setYouTubeDataApi(youTubeDataApi);
    return fragment;
}

public YouTubeRecyclerViewFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public void setYouTubeDataApi(YouTube api) {
    mYouTubeDataApi = api;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mPlaylistIds = getArguments().getStringArray(ARG_YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_IDS);
    }

    // start fetching the playlist titles
    new GetPlaylistTitlesAsyncTask(mYouTubeDataApi) {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(PlaylistListResponse playlistListResponse) {
            // if we didn't receive a response for the playlist titles, then there's nothing to update
            if (playlistListResponse == null)
                return;

            mPlaylistTitles = new ArrayList();
            for (com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Playlist playlist : playlistListResponse.getItems()) {
                mPlaylistTitles.add(playlist.getSnippet().getTitle());
            }
        }
    }.execute(mPlaylistIds);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // set the Picasso debug indicator only for debug builds
    Picasso.with(getActivity()).setIndicatorsEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    //View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.youtube_recycler_view_fragment, container, false);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.youtube_recycler_view_fragment, container, false);

    //mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_recycler_view);

    // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    Resources resources = getResources();
    if (resources.getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet)) {
        // use a staggered grid layout if we're on a large screen device
        mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(resources.getInteger(R.integer.columns), StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    } else {
        // use a linear layout on phone devices
        //mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    }

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // if we have a playlist in our retained fragment, use it to populate the UI
    if (mPlaylistVideos != null) {
        // reload the UI with the existing playlist.  No need to fetch it again
        reloadUi(mPlaylistVideos, false);
    } else {
        // otherwise create an empty playlist using the first item in the playlist id's array
        mPlaylistVideos = new PlaylistVideos(mPlaylistIds[0]);
        // and reload the UI with the selected playlist and kick off fetching the playlist content
        reloadUi(mPlaylistVideos, true);
    }
}

private void reloadUi(final PlaylistVideos playlistVideos, boolean fetchPlaylist) {
    // initialize the cards adapter
    initCardAdapter(playlistVideos);

    if (fetchPlaylist) {
        // start fetching the selected playlistVideos contents
        new GetPlaylistAsyncTask(mYouTubeDataApi,getContext()) {
            @Override
            public void onPostExecute(Pair<String, List<Video>> result) {
                handleGetPlaylistResult(playlistVideos, result);
            }
        }.execute(playlistVideos.playlistId, playlistVideos.getNextPageToken());
    }
}

private void initCardAdapter(final PlaylistVideos playlistVideos) {
    // create the adapter with our playlistVideos and a callback to handle when we reached the last item
    mPlaylistCardAdapter = new PlaylistCardAdapter(playlistVideos, new LastItemReachedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLastItem(int position, String nextPageToken) {
            new GetPlaylistAsyncTask(mYouTubeDataApi,getContext()) {
                @Override
                public void onPostExecute(Pair<String, List<Video>> result) {
                    handleGetPlaylistResult(playlistVideos, result);
                }
            }.execute(playlistVideos.playlistId, playlistVideos.getNextPageToken());
        }
    });
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mPlaylistCardAdapter);
}

private void handleGetPlaylistResult(PlaylistVideos playlistVideos, Pair<String, List<Video>> result) {
    if (result == null) return;
    final int positionStart = playlistVideos.size();
    playlistVideos.setNextPageToken(result.first);
    playlistVideos.addAll(result.second);
    mPlaylistCardAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart, result.second.size());
}

/**
 * Interface used by the {@link PlaylistCardAdapter} to inform us that we reached the last item in the list.
 */
public interface LastItemReachedListener {
        void onLastItem(int position, String nextPageToken);
    }
}
```

Below is the AsyncTask class that is used to fetch videos from the playlist supplied:

```
public abstract class GetPlaylistAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Pair<String, List<Video>>> {
private static final String TAG = "GetPlaylistAsyncTask";
private static final Long YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_MAX_RESULTS = 10L;

//see: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list
private static final String YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_PART = "snippet";
private static final String YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_FIELDS = "pageInfo,nextPageToken,items(id,snippet(resourceId/videoId))";
//see: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list
private static final String YOUTUBE_VIDEOS_PART = "snippet,contentDetails,statistics"; // video resource properties that the response will include.
private static final String YOUTUBE_VIDEOS_FIELDS = "items(id,snippet(title,description,thumbnails/high),contentDetails/duration,statistics)"; // selector specifying which fields to include in a partial response.

private YouTube mYouTubeDataApi;
Context mContext;
ProgressDialog progressBar;


public GetPlaylistAsyncTask(YouTube api, Context context) {
    mYouTubeDataApi = api;
    mContext = context;
    progressBar = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
}

@Override
protected Pair<String, List<Video>> doInBackground(String... params) {
    final String playlistId = params[0];
    final String nextPageToken;

    if (params.length == 2) {
        nextPageToken = params[1];
    } else {
        nextPageToken = null;
    }

    PlaylistItemListResponse playlistItemListResponse;
    try {
        playlistItemListResponse = mYouTubeDataApi.playlistItems()
                .list(YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_PART)
                .setPlaylistId(playlistId)
                .setPageToken(nextPageToken)
                .setFields(YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_FIELDS)
                .setMaxResults(YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_MAX_RESULTS)
                .setKey(ApiKey.YOUTUBE_API_KEY)
                .execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    if (playlistItemListResponse == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get playlist");
        return null;
    }

    List<String> videoIds = new ArrayList();

    // pull out the video id's from the playlist page
    for (PlaylistItem item : playlistItemListResponse.getItems()) {
        videoIds.add(item.getSnippet().getResourceId().getVideoId());
    }

    // get details of the videos on this playlist page
    VideoListResponse videoListResponse = null;
    try {
        videoListResponse = mYouTubeDataApi.videos()
                .list(YOUTUBE_VIDEOS_PART)
                .setFields(YOUTUBE_VIDEOS_FIELDS)
                .setKey(ApiKey.YOUTUBE_API_KEY)
                .setId(TextUtils.join(",", videoIds)).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new Pair(playlistItemListResponse.getNextPageToken(), videoListResponse.getItems());
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressBar = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    progressBar.setCancelable(true);
    progressBar.setMessage("Processing Request");
    progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressBar.show();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    progressBar.setMessage("I have found :");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Pair<String, List<Video>> stringListPair) {
        progressBar.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it lost in doInBackground somewhere ? Did you debug the code?

Comment: Its not showing any error other than displaying progressBar not getting terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use listener interface, handle `onPostExecute` function like here:

[How to get the result of OnPostExecute() to main activity because AsyncTask is a separate class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a)

and change the code snippet

```
 new GetPlaylistAsyncTask(mYouTubeDataApi,getContext()) {
            @Override
            public void onPostExecute(Pair<String, List<Video>> result) {
                handleGetPlaylistResult(playlistVideos, result);
            }
        }.execute(playlistVideos.playlistId, playlistVideos.getNextPageToken());
```

as

```
 new GetPlaylistAsyncTask(mYouTubeDataApi,getContext(),YouTubeRecyclerViewFragment.this)
          .execute(playlistVideos.playlistId, playlistVideos.getNextPageToken());

    @Override
    public void handleGetPlaylistResult(PlaylistVideos playlistVideos, Pair<String, List<Video>> result) {
        if (result == null) return;
        if (playlistVideos == null){
             playlistVideos = mPlaylistVideos;
        }
        final int positionStart = playlistVideos.size();
        playlistVideos.setNextPageToken(result.first);
        playlistVideos.addAll(result.second);
        mPlaylistCardAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart, result.second.size());
    }
```

GetPlaylistAsyncTask.java

```
 public class GetPlaylistAsyncTask{

 private AsyncResponse theListener;

 public GetPlaylistAsyncTask(YouTube api, Context context, YouTubeRecyclerViewFragment frag ) {
    mYouTubeDataApi = api;
    mContext = context;
    theListener = (AsyncResponse)frag;
 }

 @Override
       public void onPostExecute(Pair<String, List<Video>> result) {
          progressBar.dismiss();
          theListener.handleGetPlaylistResult(null,result);
      }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, it is dismissing the progressBar but not showing the result.

Comment: You need to use listener check the link I have sended. Your Async class should look like that(I will update  my answer) @Rauhayl

Comment: Thank you @mismanc. I am extremely delighted to have such a valuable support from you. I created AsyncResponse class and implemented handleGetPlaylistResult() method in YouTubeRecyclerViewFragment. But GetPlaylistAsyncTask class does not recognize the playlistVideos parameter passed in handleGetPlaylistResult() from onPostExecute method.

Comment: You don't need to send `playlistVideos` parameter.  In your fragment you already have it.

Comment: Kindly review following classes to have a clear view.    AsyncResponse class  [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/22b825fea35ff25ce94c749bb7fa78bf) , GetPlaylistAsyncTask class   [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/66eb739d393928383ee2f7bc075a4464)  and YouTubeRecyclerViewFragment class [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2f2e1048917ef8746e7a8b2609e138ac)

Comment: check it out carefully @Rauhayl

Comment: Yes, I would love to accept the answer but it throwing ClassCastException at theListener = (AsyncResponse)context; I am figuring it out .. You may have a look at it too. [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/941c95615e5fc5ced719420e2ae4623c)

Comment: You are passing `getContext()` parameter. You need to pass `YouTubeRecyclerViewFragment.this` parameter. But I am not sure your progress dialog will work. So pass it as 3 parameter. I update my answer. I have just added `YouTubeRecyclerViewFragment.this` parameter to GetPlaylistAsyncTask class constructor @Rauhayl

Comment: Whoa .. Man, You are just awesome :) Thank you once again for your out of the way support. I wish I could be of any help to you. May God bless you with cherish and happiness.

Comment: You are welcome. May Allah bless you  with cherish, happiness and guidance brother . @Rauhayl